# SQL Server make varbinary(8000) A Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, varbinary

I'm confused with something.  I have a field that is varbinary(8000)  - it contains hashbytes 'SHA2_256' info.

I want to make this field a Primary key, but the limit of key is 900 bytes.

I'm not sure if I'm correct but when I do a LEN on the hashfield, it is only ever 32 in lengh.

Am I ok changing the field from varbinary(8000) to varbinary(900) so it can be a key?

Apologies, I'm not sure when it comes to varbinary

Comment: Why 900 if all the values will fit in a `varbinary(32)`.

Comment: You can even make it as short as `varbinary(32)` as the hash lengths will never exceed 256 bit = 32 byte. If you really only store that hashes in the column that is.

Comment: ah ok - sorry, I'm not familiar with VARBINARY.  That makes sense, thank you both.